# Strings ending on moving D-brane

Tags: string-theory, branes

If a fundamental string is hanging from a D-brane (with one end fixed on it) along radial direction and there is another D-brane which comes and attach to the string. What happens when the second brane moves along the radial direction? Does the string get stuck and the effective length decreases? Does the tension of the string gets modified? How should one understand the dynamics?